# "Single ampersand used with wrong catcode" error using tikz matrix in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, matrices

I am having trouble getting a basic example of a matrix of notes to show up in my beamer presentation. I am using the code copied from the pgf manual. Here is a complete working example. The error I get upon compilation is: 
"Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode."

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,fit,petri,positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
{
8 & 1 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 7 \\
4 & 9 & 2 \\
};
\draw[thick,red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 108):

Beamer messes around with catcodes a lot. From the TkiZ manual:

> TikZ makes `&` an active character and
>   then defines this character to be
>   equal to `\pgfmatrixnextcell`. In most
>   situations this will work nicely, but
>   sometimes `&` cannot be made active;
>   for instance because the matrix is
>   used in an argument of some macro or
>   the matrix contains nodes that contain
>   normal `{tabular}` environments. In
>   this case you can use the following
>   option to avoid having to type
>   `\pgfmatrixnextcell` each time:
>
> ```
> /tikz/ampersand replacement=〈macro name〉
> ```
>
> If a macro name is provided, this
>   macro will be defined to be equal to
>   `\pgfmatrixnextcell` inside matrices
>   and `&` will not be made active. For
>   instance, you could say `ampersand
>   replacement=\&` and then use `\&` to
>   separate columns.

For your example this means:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]
{
8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
3 \& 5 \& 7 \\
4 \& 9 \& 2 \\
};
\draw[thick,red,->] (magic-1-1) |- (magic-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. Thank you! I just started to learn TikZ last night and I foresee using it a -lot-. Thank you for helping me to understand some of the inner workings.

Comment: This also fixed my problem, but I still have no clue of what was happening: what exactly is an "active character" and why did it cause an error? What is a catcode? Does this always happen when using tikz-matrices in a `beamer` document?

Comment: @MHaaZ: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/what-are-category-codes

Comment: @Caramdir Why there is a problem with beamer? The `\matrix` is not used as an argument of a macro and also the nodes don't contain `{tabular}` environments.

Answer (score 44):

Simply add the `fragile` option to the frame:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
...
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Note that for this to work `\end{frame}` must be alone on a single line.

Comment: This works for me, but is there a downside?  I mean, is ```fragile``` likely to break anything else?

Comment: Somehow I had to use `\begin{frame}[fragile]` *and* `\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&] ... \& ...` to get it to work.