# Commutative Diagrams and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

I wish I knew how to draw the this commutative diagram with the TikZ package.
 [image: Requested output]

I would also like to know how to put subtitles in the diagram.

Comment: See
http://www.felixl.de/commu.pdf and http://www.jmilne.org/not/Mtikz.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a start diagram for you:

- We use a matrix for the positioning of the main nodes
- We draw edges or arrows, respectively, between the nodes, using nodes for labels
- If you would like to have a caption or subtitle, use a `figure` environment or the `caption` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em] {
     F_t(x) & F(x) \\
     A_t & A \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node [left] {$\mathcal{B}_X$} (m-2-1)
            edge [double] node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_t$} (m-1-2)
    (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} node [above] {$\exists$} (m-2-2)
    (m-1-2) edge node [right] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} (m-2-2)
            edge [dashed,-] (m-2-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: commutative diagram]

Scaling is no problem: simply scale the font by `\Large`, `\Huge` etc. The complete matrix will scale because the distances have been given in `em` units, which scale with the font size. Regarding possibly scaling arrow tips, searching the site should give some hits.

Comment: @ Stefan Kottwitz, Thank you. But the symbol $ \mathcal{B}_t $ is below the arrow. How to fix? And another thing, how do I increase the scale?

Comment: @Elias Fixed it! For scaling: there are TikZ options such as `scale=2,transform shape`, you could simply use a larger font such as by `\Large`, you can change row sep and column sep, or simply scale all by `\resizebox` or `\scalebox` of the `graphicx` package.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz: I think your example has an error, because the top arrow should be two arrows, not an arrow with two tails. What do you think?

Comment: @Martin It's for teaching how to draw such a diagram, though I explained it with very similar output. It's not an exact "draw this for me" job, correct. Two arrows can be made in a simple way too, such as by using the "yshift" option.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another option using the `positioning` library, which is nice because you specify `nodes` in terms of relative positions to one another

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% set arrows as stealth fighter jets
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % set up the nodes
    \node (E) at (0,0) {$F_t(x)$};
    \node[right=of E] (F) {$F(x)$};
    \node[below=of F] (A) {$A$};
    \node[below=of E] (Asubt) {$A_t$};
    % draw arrows and text between them
    \draw[->,double] (E)--(F) node [midway,below] {$\mathcal{B}_T$};
    \draw[->] (F)--(A) node [midway,right] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} 
                node [midway,left] {$\exists$};
    \draw[->] (Asubt)--(A) node [midway,below] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} 
                node [midway,above] {$\exists$};
    \draw[->] (E)--(Asubt) node [midway,left] {$\mathcal{B}_X$};
    \draw[dashed] (Asubt)--(F);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think generally you may want to use `anchor=base` for the nodes `A`, `F`, `E` and `Asubt`. As they are now they will be aligned wrt their center which may result not very pleasing when they contain text of different depth/height.

Comment: But be sure you put `anchor=base` before the positioning keys or they get confused...

Answer (score 7):

Always with tkz-graph

**Picture**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% unit
\SetGraphUnit{3} 

% style for vertex
\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty] 
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style = {shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt}} 

% vertices  
\Vertex[L=$A_t$]{1} 
\EA[unit=3,L=$A$](1){2} 
\NO[unit=2,L=$F_t(x)$](1){4} 
\NO[unit=2,L=$F(x)$](2){3}

%  edges  and labels 
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={midway},>=latex']  
  \draw[->,double] (4)--(3) node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_T$};
  \draw[->]        (3)--(2) node [right] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} 
                            node [left]  {$\exists$};
  \draw[->]        (1)--(2) node [below] {$\mathcal{B}_T$} 
                            node [above] {$\exists$};
  \draw[->]        (4)--(1) node [left]  {$\mathcal{B}_X$};
  \draw[dashed]    (1)--(3); 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can have a shorter code using tikz-cd:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[swap]
    F_t(x) \arrow[Rightarrow]{r}[inner sep = 1ex]{\mathcal{B}_T} 
           \arrow{d}{\mathcal{B}'_X}
  & F(x) \arrow{d}[swap]{\mathcal{B}_X}{\exists} \\  
    A_t \arrow{r}[swap]{\exists}{\mathcal{B}_T} \arrow[dashed,dash]{ur}
  & A
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: A problem editing: the 4th line of the code (ending with {\exists}\) should end with {\exists}\\

Comment: When I run this exact example I get:

! Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.

Comment: @KeithB: I presume you're doing this in beamer. Replace each `&` with `\pgfmatrixnextcell` and try again. See [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15096/7687) but `ampersand replacement` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

The following shows a commutative diagram of the homomorphism theorem. There's a subtlety, which is often forgotten, namely that you shouldn't specify row separations in absolute lenghts but in relative lengths that depend on the size of the type: in my case I am using the `em`. I specify the distance between the columns and rows is specified in multiples of the *type size* (ems), not in cm or other units that don't depend on  the type size. The advantage of this is that the distances also look good when you scale the picture. (I'm not sure if it's easy to scale the arrows....)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
\matrix[column sep={4em,between origins},
        row sep={2em}] at (0,0)
{ \node(R)   {$R$}  ; & \node(S) {$S$}; \\
  \node(R/I) {$R/I$};                   \\};
\draw[<-] (R/I) -- (R) node[anchor=east]  {$\chi$};
\draw[->] (R/I) -- (S) node[anchor=north]  {$\psi$};
\draw[->] (R)   -- (S) node[anchor=south] {$\phi$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{Huge}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
\matrix[column sep={4em,between origins},
        row sep={2em}] at (0,0)
{ \node(R)   {$R$}  ; & \node(S) {$S$}; \\
  \node(R/I) {$R/I$};                   \\};
\draw[<-] (R/I) -- (R) node[anchor=east]  {$\chi$};
\draw[->] (R/I) -- (S) node[anchor=north]  {$\psi$};
\draw[->] (R)   -- (S) node[anchor=south] {$\phi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{Huge}

\end{document}
```

This example may also be found in Chapter 5 of [*LaTeX and Friends*](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html).

Comment: @ Marc Van Dogen. Thanks, I'll study this way of making diagrams. She looks more sophisticated.

Comment: @null -- when i edited this, the notice from the "management" showed up to the effect that all urls must now begin with https -- the link for commutative diagrams doesn't work as it is now -- so if you can fix it, good.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I cannot change this and even if I did I don't have the time to change all URLs in all my answers. I don't have the time for it.