# Commutative Diagram with Elements

Tags: diagrams

I want to make a diagram that looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: I suppose the things in the middle are turned ∈s, and not downward arrows?

Comment: Can you please search for *Commutative Diagram* on this site and tell us where exactly you are stuck with those answers?

Comment: Here is a good example [Commutative Diagrams and TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45741/commutative-diagrams-and-tikz) that should get you started.

Answer (score 5):

There is a not so complicated answer using the packages `graphicx` and `xypic`. Before explaining I will straight away give my solution. It is the following:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{align*}
\xymatrix@R=10pt{
    cRing \ar[r] & Sch \\
    A \ar@{}[u]|{\rotatebox{90}{$\in$}} \ar@{|->}[r] 
            & Spec(A) \ar@{}[u]|{\rotatebox{90}{$\in$}}
}
\end{align*}
```

NOTE that diagram should of course be enclosed in `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. Of course it is not important that `align*` is used, any display-style math envisonment will do. The package `amsmath` is also just included to make `align*` available, since it is my favorite.

Now for the explanation. I will assume that you already know a little about the `xypic`. This package is really easy to use on a basic level. Here it has been used in a little more advanced way. The option `@R=10pt` between `\xymatrix` and the following `{` is an option the specifies the 'row spacing', and in this case we want it to be small so that the picture does not look silly. The top arrow is a standart arrow in `xypic` drawn with `\ar[r]` but the lower arrow has the extra symbols `@{|->}` which just specifies that we want this arrow to have that special look. In genneral it you want to rotate a symbol in LaTeX the `graphicx` package includes the command `\rotatebox` which allows for rotating element, e.g. the symbol `\in`. These symbols are placed like arrows with the command

```
\ar@{}[u]|{\rotatebox{90}{$\in$}}
```

Now `\rotatebox{90}{$\in$}` is jost a 90 degrees rotation of the symbol `\in`. The symbols `@{}` specifies that we want an 'empty' arrow, i.e. an arrow with no lines, and the symbols `|{\rotatebox{90}{$\in$}}` specify that we want `\rotatebox{90}{$\in$}` places as a lable on top of the given arrow.

Comment: instead of `align` you should be able to just use `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: Don't use `align` for a single equation.

Comment: I'm curious, why?

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}


\newcommand{\mapdef}[4]{ 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {#1};
\node (B) at (2,0) {#2};
\node (C) at (0,-1) {#3};
\node (D) at (2,-1) {#4};
%\path[|->,font=\scriptsize] 
\draw[->] (A) edge node[above] {} (B);
\draw[|->] (C) edge node[above] {} (D);
\draw[transparent] (A) edge node[rotate=90,opacity=1] {$\in$} (C);
\draw[transparent] (B) edge node[rotate=90,opacity=1] {$\in$} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

$$\mapdef{A}{B}{a}{b}$$

\end{document}

Comment: @user13372: What does this comment represent? Your current solution?

Comment: @KristianO. The spacing around `align*` and around `displaymath` (or `\[...\]`, which is the same) is different and the former is often too much for a single equation.

Comment: @egreg. Thaks, I'm still trying to learn about stuff like that, i.e. what is _good custom_ when using LaTeX, but it's slow progress.