# \downarrow in equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, equations, subequations

could you suggest me a method to write the equation with the arrow pointing down as in the picture?

I do not understand how it could be set.

i see this post:

[Undersetting an arrow beneath an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation)

[How I can code long down arrow in equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125508/how-i-can-code-long-down-arrow-in-equations)

[image]

---------------------------------------------**UPDATE**--------------------------------------

I tried this solution but I'm not satisfied, I would like the equations to be centered on a certain distance from the corresponding number.

I inserted two solutions,

First (where I imagine you will find many errors):

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\Gradu = \textit{sym}(\Gradu) + \textit{skew}(\Gradu) = \Fra{1}{2}(\Gradu + \Grad{\bar{u}})+\Fra{1}{2}(\Gradu - \Grad{\bar{u}})\\
\hspace{-10.5cm}
\Gradu = \barbII{e}+\barbII{r} \quad \text{dove :}
\begin{cases}
    \barbII{e} = \text{Velocità di Deformazione;}\\
    \barbII{r} =  \text{Velocità di Rotazione Rigida};\\
\end{cases}\\
\barbII{e} = \overbrace{\Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I}^{1}+\underbrace{\left(\barbII{e} -\Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I\right)}_{2} %\hspace{4.7cm}
\begin{cases}
1) = \text{Parte Sferica : velocità di variazione volumentrica;}\\
2) =  \text{Velocità di deformazione a volume costante};\\
\end{cases}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

Second corresponds to a part of the solution of the image;

```
\begin{gather*}
\begin{align}
\Gradu\tikzmark{enda} = \barbII{e}\tikzmark{endb} + \barbII{r}\tikzmark{endc}
\end{align}
\end{gather*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,>=latex]
([shift={(-15pt,0pt)}]pic cs:enda) |- ++(70pt,-15pt) node[right,text width=6cm] {Tensore Gradiente di Velocità Trasposto};
\draw[->,>=latex]
([shift={(-2pt,-6pt)}]pic cs:endb) |- ++(40pt,-30pt) node[right,text width=6cm] {Velocità di Deformazione};
\draw[->,>=latex]
([shift={(-2pt,-6pt)}]pic cs:endc) |- ++(25pt,-50pt) node[right,text width=6cm] {Velocità di Rotazione Rigida};
\draw[->,>=latex]
([shift={(-2pt,-6pt)}]pic cs:endb) |- ++(40pt,-80pt) node[right,text width=6cm] {
    $\barbII{e} = \Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I+\left(\barbII{e} -\Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I\right)$
};
\end{tikzpicture}    
\vspace{3cm}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\barbII{e} = \Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I+\left(\barbII{e} -\Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

but if I add another node to explain `$\barbII{e} = \Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I+\left(\barbII{e} -\Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I\right)$`, it gives me error :

```
\draw[->,>=latex]
    ([shift={(-2pt,-6pt)}]pic cs:endb) |- ++(40pt,-80pt) node[right,text width=6cm] {
        $\barbII{e} = \Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\tikzmark{ende}\I+\left(\barbII{e} -\Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{e})\I\right)$
    };
```

[image]

---------------------------------------------**UPDATE 1**----------------------------------

I chose this final solution

```
\begin{align*}
\Gradu&=\tikzmarknode{e1}{\barbII{e}}+\barbII{r}\quad
\text{dove}~\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\barbII{e}&=& \text{Velocità di Deformazione;}\\
\barbII{r}&=& \text{Velocità di Rotazione Rigida};\\
\end{array}\right.\\
&\qquad\quad \tikzmarknode{e2}{\barbII{e}}=
\overbrace{ \Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{\tau})\I}^{\text{\ding{192}}}+
\underbrace{\left(\barbII{e} -\Fra{1}{3}tr(\barbII{\tau})\I\right)}_{\text{\ding{193}}}\tikzmark{X}\quad
\begin{array}{rcl} 
\end{array}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[thick,-latex] (e1) |- (e2);
\end{tikzpicture}
Il tensore $\barbII{e}$ rappresenta pertanto la velocità di deformazione in forma (la distorsione) ed in volume e può essere decomposto in due parti:
```

%%-----------------[NUOVO COMANDO](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers)----------------------------

```
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=0.5pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[\circled{1}]Parte Sferica : Velocità di Variazione Volumentrica;
    \item[\circled{2}]Parte Deviatoria : Velocità di Deformazione a Volume Costante;
\end{itemize}
```

It would be useful to establish an **arrow distance** from `\barbII{e}`

[image]

---------------------------------------------**UPDATE 2**----------------------------------

another interesting solution

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq063}
\begin{aligned}
    \tau_{ij}=-\textbf{p}\delta_{ij}+2\mu\left( \eij-\Fra{1}{3}e_{kk}\delta_{ij}\right) 
    \text{dove $\delta_{ij}$ = }~\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
    1&\rightarrow& \text{se i = j;}\\
    0&\rightarrow& \text{se i $\neq$ j};\\
    \end{array}\right.\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[right node/.style={rectangle,draw}]
 node{%
        $\begin{aligned}
            \tikzmarknode{ex1}e_{kk}\tikzmarknode{ex2}=tr(\barbII{e})=\tikzmarknode{ex3}\Div{\bar{u}}
        \end{aligned}$};
    \draw[->,>=latex]([shift={(-70pt,-5pt)}]pic cs:ex1-ex2) |- ++(80pt,-25pt) node[right,text width=6cm] 
    { È considerata la somma degli elementi della diagonale di $\barbII{e}$ che non coinvolge gli ij;};
    \draw[->,>=latex]([shift={(-8pt,-15pt)}]pic cs:ex3) |- ++(16pt,-52pt) node[right,text width=6cm] 
    {Velocità di Deformazione Volumetrica (Comprimibiltà);};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw good arrows explaining parts of equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278718/how-to-draw-good-arrows-explaining-parts-of-equation) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145670

Comment: @Sebastiano no. I do not want the written code for me. I would like to understand how to write it.

Comment: @Antonio Instead is preferible that you add your code so we can all help you better. If you see our links are similar to your initial question.

Comment: @Sebastiano in these days I try to write the code and update the question. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @Antonio We're all available here to help you. We are waiting for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263480/undersetting-an-arrow-beneath-an-equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Sebastiano pinged me, I try to write an answer. I focus on the arrow and unfortunately do not have your macros, so I made something up, but you will of course prefer to use your own macro `\barbII`. This answer requires the latest version of `tikzmark`, which is part of the newest standard TeX distributions. You can use it to make certain elements of your formulae nodes, which you can then connect in an overlay `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\barbII}[1]{\underset{=}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \nabla \bar\mu^T&=\dots \\
 \nabla \bar\mu^T&=\tikzmarknode{e1}{\barbII{e}}+\barbII{\ddot r}\quad
 \text{dove}~\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
 \barbII{e}&=& \text{\dots}\\
 \barbII{\ddot r}&=& \text{\dots}\\
 \end{array}\right.\\
 &\qquad\quad \barbII{\tikzmarknode{e2}{e}}=
 \overbrace{\dots}^{\text{\ding{192}}}+
 \underbrace{\dots}_{\text{\ding{193}}}\tikzmark{X}\quad
 \begin{array}{rcl} \tikzmarknode{i1}{\text{\ding{192}}} & & \\
 \tikzmarknode{i2}{\text{\ding{193}}} & & \\
 \end{array}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[thick,-latex] (e1) |- (e2);
 \draw (i1) -- ([yshift=5pt]pic cs:X) -- (i2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your solution is very interesting.
I have problems with your `\ barbII {}` mine is written like this: `\ newcommand * {\ barbI} [1] {\ stackunder [1.0pt] {$ # 1 $} {\ rule {0.8ex} {0.095ex}}} %% subbarra
\ Newcommand * {\ Barbii} [1] {\ Barbi {\ Barbi {# 1}}} `

if I replace with yours, I have many problems in the previous equations.
Unfortunately, my condition as a person facing a new experience leads to bad writing of the code.