# Fine-tuning a commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to type the following simple commutative diagram in LaTeX. I have the basics, but I need for the V to be centered, and for the arrow under the g to be in the opposite direction.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
\matrix[column sep={4em,between origins},
    row sep={2em}] at (0,0)
{ \node(X)   {$X$}  ; & \node(Y) {$Y$}; \\
\node(V) {$V$};                   \\};
\draw[<-] (V) -- (X) node[anchor=east]  {$h$};
\draw[->] (V) -- (Y) node[anchor=north]  {$g$};
\draw[->] (X)   -- (Y) node[anchor=south] {$f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: To switch the direction of the arrow, just reverse the order: `\draw[->] (Y) -- (V)` instead of `\draw[->] (V) -- (Y)`.  Also, the `V` node is centered, so perhaps just increasing the length of the line a bit by adding `shorten` option as in `\draw[->, shorten >=-0.5ex] (Y) -- (V)` makes it look _more_ centered.

Comment: have you seen [Commutative Diagrams and TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45741) and a [search for commutative diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=commutative+diagram)

Comment: @PeterGrill When I compile, I still see the V directly beneath the X,rather than centered and diagonally beneath and to the right of the X, as I would like for it to be. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelDykes: Duhh!!! Sorry about that. Not sure what part of "center" was confusing to me. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this solution with `tikz-cd` help?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
X \arrow{rr}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{h}& &Y \arrow{dl}{g}\\
& V & 
\end{tikzcd}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, it does as this is exactly what I was looking for. In general, what are the differences between tikz and tikz-cd? I mean when is it better to use the latter rather than the former? Thanks again.

Comment: I am unexpert, but as I see it, `tikz-cd` is a `tikz`-based package to easily type commutative diagrams. As you can see, the syntaxis is as easy as `xymatrix`.

Comment: You're welcome. Here is the manual for more information:  http://ctan.unixbrain.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf