# How can I draw this commutative diagram for function composition?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, xy-pic

I am working on a project, and need to add a diagram that displays a commutative diagram illustrating basic function composition similar to what is on page 17 in the image attached. I would like to make it look a bit "nicer" for lack of a better term though. I really do not know where to even begin however. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Here is a beginning. While I realize it is only a beginning, it is all I have been able to put together thus far. Thanks:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{ X & & Y \\
& V & \\ };
%\draw[double,double distance=5pt] (m-1-1) – (m-1-3);
\path[-,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-1) edge node[auto] {$ f $} (m-1-3)
edge node[description] {$ g \circ f $} (m-2-2)
(m-1-3) edge node[auto] {$ g $} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It does not have the arrows nor the ellipses I would like, but it is a start. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: What would look nicer? It would be much easier to use regular shapes (circles or ellipses) or no shapes really. The diagram you show is less a commutative diagram and more a visualization in my eyes.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I think the OP really _wants_ a visualization (for teaching purposes) rather than the commutative diagram he asks for. Drawing the sets as blobs is then a better convention.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sorry I really did just want a visualization rather than a commutative diagram. I apologize for the misnomer. Is there any way to achieve that in LaTeX?

Comment: –1: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Let me know when you added an MWE and I’d be happy to redeem my downvote ;-)

Comment: Take a look at this example (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107743/18228) and see if it's enough to get you started. If so, and you'd like to add other features to the diagram, then you can edit your post to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the option `->` to draw the arrows. To add the ellipses, load the `shapes.geometric` library, and add

```
nodes={ellipse,draw,minimum width=<length>}
```

to the list of options for the `\matrix` command. Here, `ellipse` causes the node to have an elliptical shape, `draw` draws the elliptical border of the node, and `minimum width=<length>` specifies the minimal width of the node.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
  \matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,
    row sep=3em,column sep=2.5em,
    text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex,
    nodes={ellipse,draw,minimum width=2cm},
  ]{
    X && Y \\
    & V & \\
  };
  \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
  (m-1-1) edge node[auto] {$ f $} (m-1-3)
  edge node[description] {$ g \circ f $} (m-2-2)
  (m-1-3) edge node[auto] {$ g $} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

---

## Upadate

An example that more closely resemble your picture:

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    elps/.style 2 args={draw,ellipse,minimum width=#1,minimum height=#2},
    node distance=3cm,
    font=\footnotesize,
    >=latex,
  }
  \node(x)[elps={1.3cm}{1cm},label={below left:$X$}]{};
  \node(y)[elps={2cm}{1.2cm},right=of x,label={below left:$Y$}]{};
  \node(v)[elps={1.5cm}{.9cm},below right=2cm of x,label={below left:$V$}]{};
  \fill[gray!50]($(y.center)-(5pt,5pt)$)circle[x radius=.7cm,y radius=.3cm]coordinate(im);
  \node at (im){$\mathrm{im}(f)$};
  \draw[->](x)to[bend right]node[above right]{$g\circ f$}(v);
  \draw[->](y)to[bend left]node[right]{$g$}(v);
  \draw[->](x)to[bend left=20]node[above]{$f$}(y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I think that is what I am looking for. Thanks!