# Four Node Commutative Diagram in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am quite new to LaTeX and I was curious if anyone knew how to make these sorts of diagrams. I saw one other picture on here but it was a three node diagram and I wasn't sure how to make LaTeX recognize to make a square when I inserted another node. Any ideas?

Edit: Specifically, this works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
\matrix[column sep={4em,between origins},
        row sep={2em}] at (0,0)
{ \node(R)   {$R$}  ; & \node(S) {$S$}; \\
  \node(R/I) {$R/I$};                   \\};
\draw[<-] (R/I) -- (R) node[anchor=east]  {$\chi$};
\draw[->] (R/I) -- (S) node[anchor=north]  {$\psi$};
\draw[->] (R)   -- (S) node[anchor=south] {$\phi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I need to change the starting points and destinations of arrows to allow for four nodes.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is this answer (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45747/12571) useful?

Comment: Also, there is a TikZ-based package specifically for commutative diagrams: [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd)

Comment: Yes JLDiaz, but for some reason even though I have the tikz package up and running when I paste that into my code it won't compile.

Comment: I will definitely keep that in mind as I use these more, Kevin.  Is that a default package?

Comment: @user33311 Be sure to include tikz library `matrix`.  If still does not work post a new question and include the errors you get.

Comment: @JLDiaz I just posted code from the linked article that works well for me.  Is there an easy way to edit this for four nodes?

Comment: @user33311 What you put inside the `\matrix` has the structure of a latex table, so you use `&` to make "cells" in each column, and `\\` to start a new row. So you can guess that you need to add the fourth node by adding `& \node{...}` in the code your posted, in the white space below node S.

Comment: Thank you, I should have seen that, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 24):

It's really easy with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
R \arrow{r}{\phi} \arrow[swap]{d}{\chi} & S \arrow{d}{\Psi} \\
R/I \arrow{ur}{\psi} \arrow{r}{\Phi} & T
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As JLDiaz informed you, we can make a forth node by adding an `& \node ...;`

```
\documentclass[convert = false, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={midway}]
  \matrix[column sep={4em,between origins}, row sep={2em}] at (0,0) {
    \node(R) {$R$}  ; & \node(S) {$S$}; \\
    \node(R/I) {$R/I$}; & \node (T) {$T$};\\
  };
  \draw[<-] (R/I) -- (R) node[anchor=east]  {$\chi$};
  \draw[->] (R/I) -- (S) node[anchor=north]  {$\psi$};
  \draw[->] (R) -- (S) node[anchor=south] {$\phi$};
  \draw[->] (S) -- (T) node[anchor=west] {$\Psi$};
  \draw[->] (R/I) -- (T) node[anchor=north] {$\Phi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]