# Updownarrows in commutative diagrams

Tags: diagrams

Can anybody tell me how to draw a diagram from A to B with an uparrow and a downarrow? Thanks.

Comment: For a start: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122775/34618

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[shift right=.3em,swap]{d}{f} \\ % arrow down, labeled f
B \arrow[shift right=.3em,swap]{u}{g}    % arrow up, labeled g
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some points to notice:

1. Left and right are with respect to an imaginary travel from the source to the target of the arrow;
2. `shift right` means move the arrow towards the right (as determined by the rule above;
3. the label is placed by default on the left side, but `swap` orders to change side.

The alternative format

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[shift left=.3em]{d}{f} \\ % arrow down, labeled f
B \arrow[shift left=.3em]{u}{g}    % arrow up, labeled g
\end{tikzcd}
```

which produces

[image]

should visually explain what is meant by the rules above.

The direction indicators are `d`, `u`, `l` and `r` and combinations thereof.

Comment: Thanks very much. But when I try to use the package{tikz-cd}, an error appears, saying there is no room for a new \dimen.

Comment: @ksj03 That can happen; add `\usepackage{etex}` just after the `\documentclass` line. See [No room for a new `\dimen`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38607/)

Comment: It still doesn't work!

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with pgfkeys. I don't know why.