# How to have the bold tip using xy package

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

From this old question [Commutative Diagrams and TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45741/commutative-diagrams-and-tikz/45765#45765), I have seen that there is an implies with the bold tip done with `TikZ`.

[image]

Is it possible to replicate with `xy` package to have the same tip or others bold tips?

I add a MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
$\xymatrix@1{
A\ar@{=>}[r] &B
}$
\end{document}
```