# problems with tikz and beamer and ampersands

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unknown error using tikz matrix of nodes in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/unknown-error-using-tikz-matrix-of-nodes-in-beamer)

I'm trying to write a beamer document with tikz math diagrams.
This code how gives me a " Single ampersand used with wrong catcode." error.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,shapes,snakes}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes]
    {X & Y \\ A & B \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any clues why?

(by the way, the reason I'm writing this document is for personal notes to prepare a talk. I'm only interested in the fact that text is big and the formatting is designed for a schematic text. As I don't really care about the individual slides (i.e. the frame commands), do you have any tips for good alternatives?)

Comment: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: or `ampersand replacement=\&` in matrix and use `\&` instead of `&`

Comment: thanks guys, both seem to work. is there any reason why one would be preferable?

Comment: The two methods are given in this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/unknown-error-using-tikz-matrix-of-nodes. Perhaps you question is a duplicate.

Comment: You need a wizard to compare the two methods. A lot of similar problems with beamer are solved with `fragile`but in this special case with tikz and a matrix, `ampersand replacement=\&` is the common method. I think you need to memorize the two methods.

Comment: thanks everyone. I had searched before asking the question, but apparently not deeply enough. may the tex lords lay waste on this question.