# Tikzpicture from LaTeX document does not compile in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unknown error using tikz matrix of nodes in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/unknown-error-using-tikz-matrix-of-nodes-in-beamer)

I have the following `tikzpicture` environment from my TeX document but I cannot make it work in Beamer. I get the error:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named m-1-3 is known. 
! Package pgf Error: No shape named m-1-4 is known.
```

Here is the code

```
\begin{frame}[fragile] 
\frametitle{Data set-up}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex] 
{\&\&Z_{1}\&Z_{2}\&\& \\
R \& \& \& \& \& Y  \\ };
\path[->,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-3) edge node[description]{$ \alpha_{1} $} (m-2-1)
(m-1-4) edge node[description] {$ \alpha_{2} $}(m-2-1)
(m-1-3) edge node[description]{$ \beta_{1} $} (m-2-6)
(m-1-4) edge node[description] {$ \beta_{2} $}(m-2-6);
\path[->,loosely dashed, font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-1) edge node[auto, swap] {$(MAR)$}(m-2-6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Can you please provide us your preamble, especially all your loaded packages?

Comment: and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61851/problems-with-tikz-and-beamer-and-ampersands [closed] `ampersand replacement=\&` and `fragile` are the two methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that your code uses `\&` as column separator, but the default is `&`. To use `\&` you should add the option `ampersand replacement=\&`.

This code works properly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile] 
\frametitle{Data set-up}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em,
 column sep=2.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex,
 ampersand replacement=\&] % <= notice the missing option
{\&\&Z_{1}\&Z_{2}\&\& \\
R \& \& \& \& \& Y  \\ };
\path[->,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-3) edge node[description]{$ \alpha_{1} $} (m-2-1)
(m-1-4) edge node[description] {$ \alpha_{2} $}(m-2-1)
(m-1-3) edge node[description]{$ \beta_{1} $} (m-2-6)
(m-1-4) edge node[description] {$ \beta_{2} $}(m-2-6);
\path[->,loosely dashed, font=\scriptsize]
(m-2-1) edge node[auto, swap] {$(MAR)$}(m-2-6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}    

\end{document}
```

Graphical result:

[image]

Comment: I saw the previous discussion and changed & to \&, but didn't realize how the option was inserted. Many thanks!