# Trying to get tikz-cd going

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Trying to get samples from [this document](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) to work, I made the following [minimal document on WriteLaTeX here](https://www.writelatex.com/287206snpbkt)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Hello Commutative Diagrams}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow{rd} \arrow{r}{\phi} & B \\
    & C
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and get error on next-to-last line "Single ampersand used with wrong catcode."

I try removing the ampersands or prepending a backslash to them and get "No shape named tikz@f@1-2-2 is known."

I try leaving in the backslashes before the ampersands and wrapping the `tikzcd` in `{...}` and preceding it with a `\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=3em,ampersand replacement=\&]`, which I snipped from another StackExchange answer, and I get "can't nest pgfmatrix environments yet."

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: `tikz-cd`/TikZ makes `&` active which doesn't work in a `frame` environment (for `beamer` reasons). You need to use the `ampersand replacement` option (recommended) but without wrapping everything in a `\matrix` again or use the `fragile` option. Simply write `\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]` and use `\&` instead of `&`.

Comment: This has been discussed a number of times on the site; see [Tikzpicture from LaTeX document does not compile in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62154/13304), [tikz matrix and beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69293/tikz-matrix-and-beamer?lq=1) and [Unknown error using tikz matrix of nodes in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15093/13304).

Comment: Also related [Unknown error using tikz matrix of nodes in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15093/12571)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel what would the exact syntax for the `ampersand replacement` option be in my context -- it doesn't work in the context of the `\matrix...` command that I tried above.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin:  no need for `\matrix`; simply `\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \arrow{rd} \arrow{r}{\phi} \& B \    \& C
  \end{tikzcd}`

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Exactly what Gonzalo Medine wrote in his comment. `tikz-cd` uses already a `\matrix` internally which would clash with yours. Simply specify a macro sequence (it can be (nearly) anything starting with a ``\``) with the `ampersand replacement` option and use this at the place of the `&`s. The native macro would be `\pgfmatrixnextcell` if I remember correctly.