# Referencing nodes in matrix of nodes does not work in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, matrices

When using node coordinates in a matrix of nodes in the `article` document class, the following code works well and soes exactly what it is supopsed to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]
   {
   A & B & C\\
   D & E & F\\
   };
   \draw (m-1-1)--(m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I try to get the same result in `beamer` by doing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]
      {
      A \& B \& C\\
      D \& E \& F\\
      };
      \draw (m-1-1)--(m-2-3);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

compilation fails with

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named m-2-3 is known.
```

Using a `fragile` frame makes no difference. Is there a way to make the node names in a matrix of nodes work in `beamer`?

Comment: You forgot `ampersand replacement=\&`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel OK, that was really dumb of me.  Thanks, that solves the problem. Could you make it into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Related/duplicates: [Tikzpicture from LaTeX document does not compile in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62154/13304) dup of [Unknown error using tikz matrix of nodes in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15093/13304).

Comment: Your first code with `fragile` frame option will work. Your second code without `fragile` but with `ampersand replacement=\&` will work.