# Beamer and ampersands (XeLaTeX)

Tags: beamer, xetex, ampersand

There are some known problems with ampersands and beamer ([as discussed here, for instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61851/problems-with-tikz-and-beamer-and-ampersands)), but I haven't been able to find a good reference...

Anyway, the concrete problem I have is with tables (also with amsmath environments): the ampersands break the uncover environments when compiling with XeLaTeX (but it works fine with PDFLaTeX).  In the following example, I have:

- with PDFLaTeX both C and D and greyed out in the first slide
- with XeLaTeX, only C is greyed out in the first slide

In TikZ there is a workaround to avoid ampersands, but I don't see how to do with tables or amsmath environnemnts...  Could it be a beamer bug?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatetransparentcovered
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    A & B \\
    \pause
    C & D
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May be you can use  `\visible<2>{C & D \\}`

Comment: I get the expect output with `\visible` (the second line only visible on the second slide) , but if I change it to `\uncover`, I don't get the expected output with XeLaTeX (the second line grayed out in the first slide)

Comment: I don't know why you need XeLaTeX, but if it is just because of the extended font support you could also use LuaTeX. Your MWE seems to work fine with it.

Answer (score 2):

If `xetex` does not like the &'s, than don't use them. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276133/36296 shows how to use other symbols as alignment markers for the table (maybe using a space is not the best idea, just change it to something that suits you).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatetransparentcovered

\newenvironment{mytabular}[2][c]{%
    \catcode`\&=10
    \catcode`\ =4
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}
    }{%
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            A & B \pause \\
            C & D
        \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{mytabular}{cc}
                    A B\\\pause
                    C D
        \end{mytabular}
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]