# Changing the alignment character (default: &) in tabular-like environments

Tags: tables, strings, ampersand

I want to define a simple tabular environment that treats spaces as the column separators. So something like `a b c d` should be treated as `a & b & c & d`. I've tried using `\StrSubstitute` but it doesn't seem possible to cheat it to replace the space with an `&`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some background and motivation? What did you try with `\StrSubstitute`?

Comment: dee: Could you give feedback on the solutions here?

Comment: On trying again with \StrSubstitute, it actually does work. In other words something like \StrSubstitute{ }{&}{blah blah} does produce blah&blah, and works fine as long as you do the substitution in each line of the table.

I was trying to use \StrSubstitute inside a {parse lines} environment, and that was failing. So \StrSubstitute is still not a good solution to create a new environment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem with `a b c d` approach is that multiple spaces between the content would be interpreted as additional column separators, i.e. erroneously typed space characters could be treated as 'extra tab alignment' characters

However, here is way how to do this:

The `&` character has catcode `4` (*alignment tab*) whereas `space` has catcode `10` (*space*).

It's necessary to give `space` the catcode `4` then (and `&` another one, say `10`, to be enabled to use 'spaces' still in a column.

I applied this redefinition of catcodes inside of a new tabular environment which replicates basically the traditional `tabular`. If other features from other tabular environments should be used -- add them please yourself, I leave that as homework ;-)

Since this redefinition occurs in a group, it does not leak outside.

I've shown this approach and a traditional table, where the vertical lines are just used to provide the look of table and showing the additional spacings.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newenvironment{mytabular}[2][c]{%
  \catcode`\&=10
  \catcode`\ =4
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}
}{%
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
a b c d a&word 
\end{mytabular}

\vskip\baselineskip
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
a & b &  c & d & a word
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Just in case it isn't entirely obvious to all, you may want to state explicitly that with this swapping of the catcodes of `&` and ` ` (space),  multiple spaces are no longer allowed as they'd get misinterpreted as multiple column separators.

Comment: @Mico: Hm, well, I thought it was obvious, but I can add it `explicitly` ;-) Thanks for suggestion

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks! Exactly the sort of stuff I had in mind.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the content, `pgfplotstable` might be appropriate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space]{
A B C D
-2.35 -2.27 -32.94 134.32
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works for my purposes too!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It allows both single and *multiple* instances of whitespace characters -- space, tab, and newline characters -- to indicate a column separator.  It works with all `tabular`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`,  and `tabulary` environments.

Two comments:

- If a cell contains two or more words separated by spaces, these spaces will need to be replaced with a special character before processing. In the example below, I suggest using the `#` character for "real" spaces.
- To generate empty cells, use either `{}` or `&&` (the latter without adjoining spaces). See the example below for applications.

The solution works as follows: A Lua function called `sp2amp` (short for "space to ampersand") is set up. It first checks if the input line being processed is inside a `tabular`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`, or `tabulary` environment; if so, it sets the Boolean variable `ok_2_process` to "true". (If you need to extend the scope of the function to include `longtable` environments, do let me know -- it's not difficult to generalize the `if` conditions.) If and only if `ok_2_process` is equal to "true", all instances of one more more whitesspace characters in the input line are replaced with `&`, and all instances of `#` are replaced with  (a single space character). By assigning the Lua function to the `process_input_buffer` callback, its work is done at a very early stage of processing, *before* TeX's "eyes" -- let alone its "mouth" and "stomach" -- get to do their work.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}
\begin{luacode}
ok_to_process = false
function sp2amp ( line )
  if string.find ( line , "\\begin{tabular[%*xy]?}" ) then
     ok_to_process = true
  elseif string.find ( line , "\\end{tabular[%*xy]?}" ) then
     ok_to_process = false
  elseif ok_to_process then
      line = string.gsub ( line , "%s+", "&" )
      line = string.gsub ( line , "#", " " )
  end
  return line
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", sp2amp, "sp2amp")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{l|}}
a  b c  
   d    A#complete#sentence.\\
e&&g {} i
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with Lua so I prefer the above solutions, but this works too!