# Threeparttable over two columns in landscape

Tags: landscape, threeparttable, tablenotes

I have a long table with several panels. I want to spread it over two columns in a landscape format. I am using `\threeparttable` to include table notes. I have tried to get this done both with `\minipage` and with `\tabularx`, but I run into several problems:
1. The two columns are not aligned. Since the second part of the table is shorter, it ends up being placed in the middle of the column instead of the top.
2. The table notes are only under the first column. I want them over the length of the entire table. I have tried to insert a third mini page or tabular, but this didn't work.
3. I also want to make sure the caption goes over the entire length of the tables.
4. The scaling is somewhat off. I want the table to fill more of the page, but with the table notes still visible. I am using `\adjustbox` to fit the table. 
Here is a MWS:

```
  \documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
   \usepackage{lscape}
   \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{adjustbox}
   \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
   \usepackage[english]{babel} % English
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{layout}
   \usepackage{setspace}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{PanelA}
  \midrule
    & Mean & SD & Median & Min & Max & N \\
   Variable A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
   Variable B & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
   \midrule 
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{PanelB}
   \midrule
       & Mean & SD & Median & Min & Max & N \\
      Variable A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
      Variable B & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
   \midrule 
 \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
 \hspace{2mm}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
  \multicolumn{7}{l}{PanelA}
  \midrule
    & Mean & SD & Median & Min & Max & N \\
   Variable A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
   Variable B & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
   \midrule 
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{PanelB}
   \midrule
       & Mean & SD & Median & Min & Max & N \\
      Variable A & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
      Variable B & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
   \midrule 
 \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
 \begin{tablenotes}
 \item Table notes are here and should go over the entire length of the table.
 \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your example doesn't compile without errors.

Comment: see if answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394795/how-to-use-the-full-textwidth-for-tablenotes-under-multiple-tables/394803#394803 can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten packages in the preamble. Just added them, so it should compile without errors now.

Comment: @ZoeFrance, is answer below what you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

based on answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394795/how-to-use-the-full-textwidth-for-tablenotes-under-multiple-tables/394803#394803) and adopted to `landscape` format:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{\clearpage}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{p{0.45\linewidth}
                             @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             p{0.45\linewidth}}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{6}{c}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{PanelA}            \\
    \midrule
            & Mean  & SD & Median & Min & Max & N \\
Variable A  & 1     & 2  & 3      & 4   & 5   & 6 \\
Variable B  & 1     & 2  & 3      & 4   & 5   & 6 \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{PanelB}          \\
    \midrule
            & Mean  & SD & Median & Min & Max & N \\
Variable A  & 1     & 2  & 3      & 4   & 5   & 6 \\
Variable B  & 1     & 2  & 3      & 4   & 5   & 6 \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular*}
&
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{6}{c}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{PanelA}            \\
    \midrule
            & Mean  & SD & Median & Min & Max & N \\
Variable A  & 1     & 2  & 3      & 4   & 5   & 6 \\
Variable B  & 1     & 2  & 3      & 4   & 5   & 6 \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{PanelB}          \\
    \midrule
            & Mean  & SD & Median & Min & Max & N \\
Variable A  & 1     & 2  & 3      & 4   & 5   & 6 \\
Variable B  & 1     & 2  & 3      & 4   & 5   & 6 \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{tabular*}%
\begin{tablenotes}
\item Table notes are here and should go over the entire length of the table.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```