# \setcapwidth is ignored if \setkomafont{caption} is used (KOMA)?

Tags: captions, koma-script

A document of mine ignored the `\setcapwidth` parameters that I set in order to get a more narrow caption. After a long search, I found that it started to work when I commented out the line `\setkomafont{caption}{\sffamily\footnotesize}`.

This is the output with the line not commented out:
[image: Line not commented out.]

This is the output with the line commented out:

[image: Line commented out.]

Am I doing something wrong? What do I have to do to use both?

Here is the Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\setkomafont{caption}{\sffamily\footnotesize} % This is the line in question

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
\footnotesize
  \centering
  \setcapwidth[c]{8cm}
  \caption{This is a rather long caption for a table that is comparatively narrow --- but it's a test}  
  \label{table:setcapwidth_table}  
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l r r @{}}
    \toprule
        Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 \\
    \midrule
        2011& 10,000 & 10,000 \\ 
        2012 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
        2013 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: What I marked as "Rows" are obviously "Columns"...

Comment: This will be fixed in KOMA-Script version 3.34, see https://komascript.de/release3.33 (German). You could use [the prerelease](https://komascript.de/node/1801) to test the bug fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the option:

```
[captions=nooneline]
```

fixes the problem.

I removed `captions=`,  when I revised the answer (added more caption option), and it stopped working again. Confusing. If you remove `\footnotesize`, it also works as expected. This is not a bug, as @esdd explain in the comment below. With default `captions=oneline`, `\setcapwidth` only effects captions that is more than *one* line, *i.e:* wider than the text width. So when you reduce font size as you did, the caption fits within the text width again, and becomes a one line caption, even if it is wider than the value you gave `\setcapwidth`. It will not be changed by `\setcapwidth`. Good to know!

In stead of `[captions=nooneline]`, you may use a centred, `\minipage`-environment of the width you prefer (here 8cm), and centre the table within that environment:

**Example 1 – centred `minipage`**

[image]

```
\documentclass[captions=nooneline, captions=tableabove]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs, relsize}

\setkomafont{caption}{\sffamily\footnotesize} % This is the line in question

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
\centering
  \footnotesize
  \begin{minipage}{8cm}
\centering
  \caption{This is a rather long caption for a table that is comparatively narrow --- but it's a test}  
  \label{table:setcapwidth_table}  
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l r r @{}}
    \toprule
        Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 \\
    \midrule
        2011& 10,000 & 10,000 \\ 
        2012 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
        2013 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – threeparttable**

Also, you may enclose the tabular-environment in a [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) if you prefer to match the width of the caption with the width of the tabular. As an added benefit, you may have nice, integrated table notes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[captions=nooneline, captions=tableabove]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable}

\setkomafont{caption}{\sffamily\footnotesize} % This is the line in question

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tbp]
\footnotesize
  \centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{This is a rather long caption for a table that is comparatively narrow --- but it's a test}  
  \label{table:setcapwidth_table}  
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l r r @{}}
    \toprule
        Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 \\
    \midrule
        2011& 10,000 & 10,000 \\ 
        2012 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
        2013 & 10,000 & 10,000 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the threeparttable solution does not work for me: I want the caption to be wider than the table, just not as long as the whole line. I found[these solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164589/table-width-with-threeparttable-smaller-than-notes-and-caption), but when I adjusted `\TPTminimum` to give more space to the caption, the table was not centered anymore. And when I put the caption outside of threeparttable (one of the suggested solutions), I am back to square one.

Comment: @anbeck It is possible to use a `\minipage`-environment, see updated answer.

Comment: I think adding `captions=nooneline` made it work for me. But as you said you had problems with it, I'll do some more tests.

Comment: With the default setting `caption=oneline` the usage of `\setcapwidth` affects only captions wider than `\textwidth`. And without `\footnotesize` (i.e. with \normalsize) the caption in the question is wider than `\textwidth`. While there is no really need to use a minipage with option `captions=nooneline`, the minipage solves the issue with  the default `captions=online`. Then a caption smaller than the argument of `\setcapwidth` will be still centered above the table.