# Trying to create a simple binomial tree in beamer

Tags: beamer, tikz-trees

Following the example in
["Single ampersand used with wrong catcode" error using tikz matrix in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/unknown-error-using-tikz-matrix-of-nodes-in-beamer/194108#194108)
I removed the errors I got but the tree is still not produced correctly.
I am trying to reproduce in beamer what I saw in this thread:
http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=7846&sid=2129f08cf0ff8d6a5473794a64bdf5ac

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdflatex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\mode<presentation>

\usetheme{JuanLesPins}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}

\title[Investment Science II]{ Investment Science II \\  Introduction to Binomial Trees }
\author[ Anonymous]

{ Investment Science II }

\institute{ Blah University }

\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix (tree) [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&]

          {
          \&   \& F \\

          \& C \&   \\

      \$A \&   \& E \\

          \& B \&   \\

          \&   \& D \\
    };

    \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [midway,above] {$p$};

    \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-4-2) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)$};

    \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) node [midway,above] {$p^2$};

    \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)p$};

    \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,above] {$(1-p)p$};

    \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)^2$};

  \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have too much empty lines in your code. Empty lines cause paragraph breaks. Remove at least the empty lines after `author` and after beginning the matrix. Better more.

It's not produced correctly, because you forgot to specify node size, column sep and row sep.

This works correctly:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdflatex,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=30}
\title[Investment Science II]{ Investment Science II \\
  Introduction to Binomial Trees }
\author[ Anonymous]{ Investment Science II }
\institute{ Blah University }
\begin{document}
\frame{\maketitle}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,sloped]
    \matrix (tree) [%
      matrix of nodes,
      minimum size=1cm,
      column sep=3.5cm,
      row sep=1cm,ampersand replacement=\&
    ]
    {
          \&   \& F \\
          \& C \&   \\
      \$A \&   \& E \\
          \& B \&   \\
          \&   \& D \\
    };
    \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-2-2) node [midway,above] {$P$};
    \draw[->] (tree-3-1) -- (tree-4-2) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)$};
    \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-1-3) node [midway,above] {$P^2$};
    \draw[->] (tree-2-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)p$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-3-3) node [midway,above] {$(1-p)p$};
    \draw[->] (tree-4-2) -- (tree-5-3) node [midway,below] {$(1-p)^2$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output tree]