# Equalize matrix with a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I could not equalize the matrices with the line and square properly. Also, is it possible to write its 3-dimensional version, that is, a 3-dimensional matrix equalized with a cube?

```
\begin{equation}
(\square,\square,\square,\cdots,\square)=\noindent\rule{2cm}{0.3pt}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\square & \square & \dots & \square \\
\square & \square & \dots & \square \\
\hdotsfor{4} \\
\square & \square & \dots & \square
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,0);
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,-1) -- (2,-1) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Please add a full MWE that we also know, which packages you're using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessed the packages you're using and probably this is a viable soultion for you. Just place the square inside a matrix and use the `raise` argument of the `\rule` [command](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Rules_and_Struts)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
(\square,\square,\square,\cdots,\square)=\noindent\rule[0.5ex]{3em}{0.55pt}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\square & \square & \dots & \square \\
\square & \square & \dots & \square \\
\hdotsfor{4} \\
\square & \square & \dots & \square
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,0);
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,-1) -- (2,-1) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: solution]

Comment: thank you so much. But what about the three-dimensional case? is it possible to write it or not?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the 3-D case isn't reffered to as matrix, nevertheless, probably [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300109/simple-visualization-of-3d-matrix) helps you

Comment: Ok then. Thanks.