# Write a 3D matrix in latex with equation environment

Tags: matrices, 3d, tikz-matrix, nicematrix

I am trying to write a 3D matrix in latex, that is of the following form:

[image]

I have checked few answers in this forum but they don't tell how [to include the equation in the tickpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300109/simple-visualization-of-3d-matrix) environment. Moreover, the shape is not really what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution requires two steps: **(1)** the construction of the two matrices and **(2)** the layout of the matrices and the drawing of the lines.

For the first step I used the package `nicematrix`. For the second step a `tikzpicture`.

For convenience I defined two commands with the arrays to be able to change them without interfering with the tikz layout.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\matrixA}{% 
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}
a_{11}^{1}  &a_{12}^{1} & \Cdots        &a_{1m}^{1}\\
\Vdots      &\Ddots     &               & \\
            &           &               &\\
a_{nm}^{1}  &           &               & a_{nm}^{1}\\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}$
}   

\newcommand{\matrixB}{% 
    $\begin{bNiceMatrix}
    a_{11}^{m}  &a_{12}^{m} & \Cdots        &a_{1m}^{m}\\
    \Vdots      &\Ddots     &               & \\
    &           &                           &\\
    a_{nm}^{m}  &           &               & a_{nm}^{m}\\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}$
}   


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (matA) {\matrixA};
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above right = 10pt and 10pt of matA, scale=0.8] (matB) {\matrixB};
    \node[left= 0pt of matA] {$A=$};
    \draw[blue,shorten >=3mm, shorten <=4mm, dotted] (matA.north west)-- (matB.north west);
    \draw[blue,shorten >=3mm, shorten <=2mm, dotted] (matA.north east)-- (matB.north east);
    \draw[blue,shorten >=3mm, shorten <=2mm, dotted] (matA.south east)-- (matB.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, is there a way to have dots instead of the blue lines?

Comment: @Wallflower Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: You need a closing bracket for ```end{document}```. Took me few minutes to notice ;)