# Matrix node inside foreach loop give error when multiple columns

Tags: foreach, tikz-matrix

This question is different from `\foreach` inside `\matrix` questions [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60394/tikz-foreach-inside-matrix) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22275/foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix). I was trying to do this question [3dmatrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300109/simple-visualization-of-3d-matrix). The `\matrix` command, when put inside `\foreach` gives the following error *when multiple columns are present*.

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options l.28 } The control
>   sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
>   \def'ed. If you have...

The M(N)WE

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
{
    \node at(\x, 1){\x};
}

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
{
\matrix [red] at(\x, 0)
{
\node {1}; \\
\node {2}; \\
\node {3}; \\
\node {4}; \\
};
}
% remove the % for the following code
%\foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
%{
\matrix [blue] at (2,0)
{
\node {1}; & \node {2}; \\
};
%}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a workaround for this situation?
(I am using texlive 2015, tikz version is `tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)`)

Also, in order to see if it is due some typo I made, I copy pasted matrix examples from pgf manual inside the foreach and it still did not work.

[image: matrix inside foreach]

### Update

As per these questions, [matrix path in another macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285654/why-is-my-matrix-path-failing-when-put-inside-another-macro?rq=1) and [shortcut for matrices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices), I am now able to put matrices in for loops by declaring macros. <strike>But now I can't access the loop variables.</strike>

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (5, 1);

\foreach \x in {0,2,...,4}
{
\begin{scope}[xshift=\x cm]
\matrix [draw,ampersand replacement=\&]{\node {1}; \&%
\node {\x};\\
\node {3}; \&%
\node {\x};\\};
\end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question so that later searches with `\matrix inside \foreach` will turn up a result (and it will point to the earlier helpful posts ([Why is my \matrix path failing when put inside another macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285654/why-is-my-matrix-path-failing-when-put-inside-another-macro?rq=1) ) & ([Problem with defining shortcuts for TikZ matrices.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices) )).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-1,-1) rectangle (5, 1);

\foreach \x in {0,2,...,4}
{
\begin{scope}[xshift=\x cm]
```

The required option

```
\matrix [draw,ampersand replacement=\&]{\node {1}; \&%
```

rest of the code

```
\node {\x};\\
\node {3}; \&%
\node {\x};\\};
\end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```