# Tikz matrix inside foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I want to draw a matrix inside foreach but the compiling is aborted due to some errors. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1}{
    \node[xshift=\x em,yshift=\x em]{\x};
    \matrix[xshift=\x em,yshift=\x em]{
        \node{A};&\node{B};\\
        \node{C};&\node{D};\\
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What's wrong with this code? The `node` inside the `foreach` is no problem but the `matrix` is.

Comment: What is the error? take a look at these questions also. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285654/why-is-my-matrix-path-failing-when-put-inside-another-macro?rq=1    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1111/problem-with-defining-shortcuts-for-tikz-matrices    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300122/matrix-node-inside-foreach-loop-give-error-when-multiple-columns/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the links (@ArunDebray @LoopSpace @StefanKottwitz)in my comments above, the `ampersand replacement` option when passed to matrix node results in a compilable document.

[image: matrix inside tiks foreach]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,5}{
    \node[xshift=\x em,yshift=\x em]{\x};
    \matrix[xshift=\x em,yshift=\x em,ampersand replacement=\&]{
        \node{A};\&\node{B};\\
        \node{C};\&\node{D};\\
    };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```