# \usetikzlibrary{babel} does not work in exsheets’ question environment

Tags: babel, tikz-cd, exsheets

I am trying to type math exercises by using XeLaTeX, the `tikz-cd` package for commutative diagrams, the `babel` package for German, and the `exsheets` package for formatting and organizing the questions and answers.
Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}
  \begin{question}
    \[
      \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
           A \arrow[r, "f"]
        \& B
      \end{tikzcd}
    \]
  \end{question}
\end{document}
```

I use `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` because otherwise the `ngerman` module for `babel` and the `"` character in the `tikzcd` environment result in a problem similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw).
I use `ampersand replacement=\&` for the `tikzcd` enviroment, because the `question` environment otherwise results in a problem similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer).

The given code results in the following error:

```
Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }
```

This is the same error one gets when not using `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`, and any of these three make the code work:

- Not using the `babel` package.
- Not using the `question` environment.
- Removing the label `"f"` from the arrow.

So it seems to me that the `question` environment is somehow preventing `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` from working.
I don’t know how the fix this, and the only [other mention of this problem](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues/30/error-when-using-the-babel-package) I found has a workaround specific to the Spanish language.

Comment: The `question` environment (actually a subenvironment, but it's not important) absorbs the contents as a macro to an argument; this is the reason why `ampersand replacement` is needed. This unfortunately also has the consequence that the trick used by the `babel` TikZ library doesn't work. However, you can use the alternate input `\arrow{r}{f}`.

Comment: @egreg: According to the tikzcd manual this notation exists for backwards compatibility, so I’m not sure if this is the best solution. But it’s a solution nonetheless, so if you post this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the `tikz-cd` package should offer a key for the arrow label, in addition to the `"<label>"` syntax. Unfortunately, the syntax `label=f` doesn't seem to work, with `tikz-cd`.

The issue here is that the `question` environment absorbs the text up to `\end{question}` as the argument to a macro (small lie, it's a subenvironment, actually, that does it), so the `babel` library can't really do its work.

You have two possibilities.

1. Use the “older” syntax `\arrow{r}{f}`
2. Surround the environment's text with `\scantokens`:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage{exsheets}
   \usepackage{tikz-cd}
   \usetikzlibrary{babel}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{question}
   \[
   \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
   \scantokens{
     A \arrow[r,"f"]
     \& B
   }
   \end{tikzcd}
   \]
   \end{question}

   \end{document}
   ```

Don't use `xltxtra`, it's not really that useful nowadays.