# Tikzpicture: How to color separate fields at the arrays and use resizebox?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, vector

I want to color only separated nodes? How could I do this? I want also resize the tikzfigure, but I got the error message `Undefined control sequence. }`

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  
\resizebox {\textwidth} {!} {
\begin{tikzpicture} [nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum width=0.2cm, minimum height=0.2cm}, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth] 

    border/.style={draw}

\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (3,10) { & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,10) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,9) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,8) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,7) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};

\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (3,4) { & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,4) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,3) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,2) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,1) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,0) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};

\draw [thick,->] (10.3,9.8) -- (10.3,9.2);
\node[] at(10.7,9.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,8.8) -- (10.3,8.2);
\node[] at(10.7,8.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,7.8) -- (10.3,7.2);
\node[] at(10.7,7.5) {$T$};

\draw [thick,->] (10.3,3.8) -- (10.3,3.2);
\node[] at(10.7,3.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,2.8) -- (10.3,2.2);
\node[] at(10.7,2.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,1.8) -- (10.3,1.2);
\node[] at(10.7,1.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,0.8) -- (10.3,0.2);
\node[] at(10.7,0.5) {$T$};

\node[] at (0.5,10) {$B_4^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{7,\$}$:};
\draw[thick,->] (4.5,10) -- node[above] {$R_0$}  (5.5,10);

\node[] at (3.5,9) {$S_{127},S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
\node[] at (1.7,8) {$S_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
\node[] at (5.3,7) {$S'_{127}$:};

\node[] at (0.5,4) {$B_5^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{3,b}$:};
\draw[thick,->] (4.5,4) -- node[above] {$R_7$}  (5.5,4);

\node[] at (5.3,3) {$S'_{127}$:};
\node[] at (3.8,2) {$S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
\node[] at (1.7,1) {$S'_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
\node[] at (5.3,0) {$S'_{126}$:};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Your editid code doesn't compile for some reason... Please fix your preamble.

Comment: I made it work and your problem was explained in this answer:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15096/120578. But if you use the way of my edited answer about the specific problem and the solution on the original question of @Zarco your result will be better. His answer deserves to be the accepted if you return to the original problem that I suggest you have to do. So, do it (return to the original different and more usefull for the forum question) and accept his answer. The new question is just a dupplicate of the link

Comment: one problem per question, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your question is not very clear to me, so i suspect, that you looking for something as you can see in the first two rows of your image:

[image]

tel me, if i'm wrong.

**edit:**

well, apparently i was misunderstood the question. coloring just one cell is simple. using the most of code from my previous answer (which is quite more concise and shorter from yours), you can rewrote your picture code as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
    mtrx/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw, minimum size=2mm},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth},
            }
\matrix (vector) [mtrx=red] at (3,10)    { & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix (vector) [mtrx=blue!30] at (10,10)  { & |[fill=red]|  % <--- define color of this cell
                                              & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[mtrx=green] at (10,9) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[mtrx] at (10,8) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[mtrx] at (10,7) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};

\matrix(vector)[mtrx] at (3,4) { & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[mtrx] at (10,4) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[mtrx] at (10,3) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[mtrx] at (10,2) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[mtrx] at (10,1) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector)[mtrx] at (10,0) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};

\draw [thick,->] (10.3,9.8) -- (10.3,9.2);
\node[] at(10.7,9.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,8.8) -- (10.3,8.2);
\node[] at(10.7,8.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,7.8) -- (10.3,7.2);
\node[] at(10.7,7.5) {$T$};

\draw [thick,->] (10.3,3.8) -- (10.3,3.2);
\node[] at(10.7,3.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,2.8) -- (10.3,2.2);
\node[] at(10.7,2.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,1.8) -- (10.3,1.2);
\node[] at(10.7,1.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,0.8) -- (10.3,0.2);
\node[] at(10.7,0.5) {$T$};

\node[] at (0.5,10) {$B_4^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{7,\$}$:};
\draw[thick,->] (4.5,10) -- node[above] {$R_0$}  (5.5,10);

\node[] at (3.5,9) {$S_{127},S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
\node[] at (1.7,8) {$S_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
\node[] at (5.3,7) {$S'_{127}$:};

\node[] at (0.5,4) {$B_5^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{3,b}$:};
\draw[thick,->] (4.5,4) -- node[above] {$R_7$}  (5.5,4);

\node[] at (5.3,3) {$S'_{127}$:};
\node[] at (3.8,2) {$S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
\node[] at (1.7,1) {$S'_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
\node[] at (5.3,0) {$S'_{126}$:};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the question is not really clear too... But with "separate nodes" the OP possibly means what is in my answer's photo. May be it's my mistake... but let's wait for his reaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to color only one field and not the entire array. I  will update my question. Sorry if the description was to bad.

Comment: @koleygr, permanently you win in guessing! congratulation and +1!

Comment: @ikreb, see edited answer!

Comment: @Zarko.. You win (+1 enough time before).

Answer (score 4):

The only easy solution that I found is to use nested tikzpictures... But it is really simple. Also used svgnames for more colors:

Code:

```
    \documentclass[tikz,svgnames]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix}
    \usepackage{pgf}

    \newcommand{\myfill}[1]%This is the command manually adjusted to do the wholev job
    {\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]   
    \draw[draw=none,fill=#1,shift={(-0.11,-0.115)}](0,0)rectangle(0.22,0.225);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum width=0.2cm, minimum height=0.2cm}, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth] 

        border/.style={draw}

    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (3,10) { & & & & & & & \\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,10) {\myfill{Red} & & &\myfill{Green} &\myfill{Brown} & & & \myfill{Blue!30!Yellow}& & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \myfill{Blue}\\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,9) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,8) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,7) { &\myfill{Green} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    };

    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (3,4) { & & & & & & & \\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,4) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,3) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,2) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,1) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    };
    \matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] at (10,0) { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    };

    \draw [thick,->] (10.3,9.8) -- (10.3,9.2);
    \node[] at(10.7,9.5) {$\oplus$};
    \draw [thick,->] (10.3,8.8) -- (10.3,8.2);
    \node[] at(10.7,8.5) {$\oplus$};
    \draw [thick,->] (10.3,7.8) -- (10.3,7.2);
    \node[] at(10.7,7.5) {$T$};

    \draw [thick,->] (10.3,3.8) -- (10.3,3.2);
    \node[] at(10.7,3.5) {$\oplus$};
    \draw [thick,->] (10.3,2.8) -- (10.3,2.2);
    \node[] at(10.7,2.5) {$\oplus$};
    \draw [thick,->] (10.3,1.8) -- (10.3,1.2);
    \node[] at(10.7,1.5) {$\oplus$};
    \draw [thick,->] (10.3,0.8) -- (10.3,0.2);
    \node[] at(10.7,0.5) {$T$};

    \node[] at (0.5,10) {$B_4^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{7,\$}$:};
    \draw[thick,->] (4.5,10) -- node[above] {$R_0$}  (5.5,10);

    \node[] at (3.5,9) {$S_{127},S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
    \node[] at (1.7,8) {$S_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
    \node[] at (5.3,7) {$S'_{127}$:};

    \node[] at (0.5,4) {$B_5^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{3,b}$:};
    \draw[thick,->] (4.5,4) -- node[above] {$R_7$}  (5.5,4);

    \node[] at (5.3,3) {$S'_{127}$:};
    \node[] at (3.8,2) {$S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
    \node[] at (1.7,1) {$S'_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
    \node[] at (5.3,0) {$S'_{126}$:};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit: After OPS Edit:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,matrix}

\newcommand{\myfill}[1]%This is the command manually adjusted to do the wholev job
{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]   
\draw[draw=none,fill=#1,shift={(-0.13,-0.13)}](0,0)rectangle(0.255,0.26);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  
\resizebox {\textwidth} {!} {
\begin{tikzpicture} [nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum width=0.2cm, minimum height=0.2cm}, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth] 

    border/.style={draw}

\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (3,10) { \myfill{green}\& \myfill{red}\& \& \& \& \& \& \myfill{brown}\\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,10) { \& \& \myfill{yellow}\& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,9) { \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,8) { \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,7) { \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};

\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (3,4) { \&\myfill{green} \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,4) { \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,3) { \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,2) { \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,1) { \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};
\matrix(vector)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw},ampersand replacement=\&,] at (10,0) { \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \& \\
};

\draw [thick,->] (10.3,9.8) -- (10.3,9.2);
\node[] at(10.7,9.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,8.8) -- (10.3,8.2);
\node[] at(10.7,8.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,7.8) -- (10.3,7.2);
\node[] at(10.7,7.5) {$T$};

\draw [thick,->] (10.3,3.8) -- (10.3,3.2);
\node[] at(10.7,3.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,2.8) -- (10.3,2.2);
\node[] at(10.7,2.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,1.8) -- (10.3,1.2);
\node[] at(10.7,1.5) {$\oplus$};
\draw [thick,->] (10.3,0.8) -- (10.3,0.2);
\node[] at(10.7,0.5) {$T$};

\node[] at (0.5,10) {$B_4^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{7,\$}$:};
\draw[thick,->] (4.5,10) -- node[above] {$R_0$}  (5.5,10);

\node[] at (3.5,9) {$S_{127},S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
\node[] at (1.7,8) {$S_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
\node[] at (5.3,7) {$S'_{127}$:};

\node[] at (0.5,4) {$B_5^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{3,b}$:};
\draw[thick,->] (4.5,4) -- node[above] {$R_7$}  (5.5,4);

\node[] at (5.3,3) {$S'_{127}$:};
\node[] at (3.8,2) {$S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
\node[] at (1.7,1) {$S'_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
\node[] at (5.3,0) {$S'_{126}$:};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, please next time post a compilable MWE. (No documentclass and `\begin{document}` was there).

Comment: Updated answer colors with more accuracy.

Comment: Sorry, I updated it. One question, whe does resizebox doesn't work with your solution? To ask a new question is not usefull or?

Comment: @ikreb I think you can just edit your question with the change.. It's ok for me to select a better answer later that does both.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that makes use of `\resizebox`. All you need to do is to put the tikzpicture in a lrbox. As for your real question, you only need to put `|[fill=red]|` in a given cell to fill the cell. I add some examples to the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,matrix,positioning}
\newsavebox\picbox
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  
\begin{lrbox}{\picbox}
\begin{tikzpicture} [nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum width=0.2cm, minimum height=0.2cm}, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth] 
    border/.style={draw}
\matrix(vector-1)[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] { & |[fill=red]| & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-2)[right=2cm of vector-1,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-3)[below=1cm of vector-2,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-4)[below=1cm of vector-3,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-5)[below=1cm of vector-4,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & &
|[fill=blue]| & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};

\matrix(vector-6)[below=6.5cm of vector-1,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-7)[right=2cm of vector-6,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & & &
|[fill=yellow]| & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-8)[below=1cm of vector-7,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-9)[below=1cm of vector-8,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}] { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-10)[below=1cm of vector-9,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
\matrix(vector-11)[below=1cm of vector-10,matrix of nodes, nodes={draw}]  { & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
};
%
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X-1)}] in {3,4,8,9,10}
{\draw[thick,-latex] (vector-\Y) -- (vector-\X) node[midway,right]{$\oplus$};}
%
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X-1)}] in {5,11}
{\draw[thick,-latex] (vector-\Y) -- (vector-\X) node[midway,right]{$T$};}
%
\draw[thick,-latex] (vector-1) -- (vector-2) node[midway,above]{$R_0$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (vector-6) -- (vector-7) node[midway,above]{$R_7$};
%
\node[left=2mm of vector-1,anchor=east] {$B_4^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{7,\$}$:};
%
\node[left=2mm of vector-3,anchor=east] {$S_{127},S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
\node[left=2mm of vector-4,anchor=east] {$S_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
\node[left=2mm of vector-5,anchor=east] {$S'_{127}$:};
%
\node[left=2mm of vector-6,anchor=east]{$B_5^0\leftarrow\mathcal{B}_{3,b}$:};
%
\node[left=2mm of vector-8,anchor=east] {$S'_{127}$:};
\node[left=2mm of vector-9,anchor=east] {$S_0,S_{24},S_{50},S_{75},S_{102}$:};
\node[left=2mm of vector-10,anchor=east] {$S'_{127}\oplus S_0\oplus S_{24}\oplus S_{50}\oplus S_{75}\oplus S_{102}\oplus R_0(B_0^0)$:};
\node[left=2mm of vector-11,anchor=east] {$S'_{126}$:};
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox\picbox}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A word of caution: it is quite possible that someone may copy my code, add some feature like `chains`, and claim that this code then becomes much more "concise". I'd kindly ask you to check if this really the case. Your code is already very well structured and thus easy to understand and adjustable. I used used positioning because I think it is advantageous here, and also use `\foreach` loops to repeat things. Personally I would refrain from using chains here for several reasons, one of them being that you lose some flexibility of adjusting positions. Likewise, you could define styles for repeating things, but your code is so well structured that I don't think that makes a big difference. So this is just to say that if someone claims to be more "concise" you should critically ask yourself if that's really true.