# newcommand for picture tikz matrix, wich separator to use?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I would like to create a new command to easily insert 4 pictures that will be arranged in a matrix, but I don't know wich separator to use in the main file. I always get the latex error "unknow graphics extension .jpg;pix... I tryed it with comma and others as well. Or am I doing something else wrong?

MnWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %required for relative positioning of nodes

%-------------------

\newcommand\twoXtwo[4]{
    \clearpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [matrix] (matrix2x2) at (current page.center) {
            \node {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#1}}; & \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#2}}; \\
            \node {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#3}}; & \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#4}}; \\
            };
     \end{tikzpicture}
}

%-------------------

\begin{document}

\twoXtwo{pix1.jpg;pix2.jpg; pix3.jpg; pix4.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In principle you could just do `\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\twoXtwo[4]{
    \clearpage
 \begin{tabular}{c@{}c}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#1} & \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#2} \\
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#3} & \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#4} \\
     \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\twoXtwo{example-image}{example-image-a}{example-image-b}{example-image-duck}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of things:

- I would recommend using the `matrix` tikz library as it was designed for this purpose. This defines the `\matrix` command which works like an array in maths mode.
- When calling the `twoXtwo` command each argument should be in its own braces (this was what LaTeX was complaining about).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx} % Draft option for placeholder images

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for drawing custom shapes
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} %required for relative positioning of nodes
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} % Matrix library
%-------------------

\newcommand\twoXtwo[4]{
    \clearpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    % Matrix of nodes. N.B. ampersand replacement (see below)
    \matrix [matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&] at (current page.center) { 
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#1} \& \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#2} \\
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#3} \& \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#4} \\
            };
     \end{tikzpicture}
}

%-------------------

\begin{document}
\twoXtwo{foo.png}{foo.png}{foo.png}{foo.png} % Arguments in individual braces
\end{document}
```

You would use `\twoXtwo{pix1.jpg}{pix2.jpg}{pix3.jpg}{pix4.jpg}`, assuming each of these images is in the same directory as your main `.tex`.

Note the use of `ampersand replacement=\&`. This is to avoid the error described [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer)

Output:

[image: example output]

Comment: thanks! I totally forgot to load the \usetikzlibrary{matrix} that was the problem, so it didn't work in extra braces either, bu now it is working fine. Good idea with the ampersand replacement=\& and the [draft] option for graphicx is nice too! In my real document I have an extra path for the pix, but globally defined, so that is fine.