# Beamer doesn't compile a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, diagrams, tikz-matrix

I'm trying to write a presentation in beamer about something I've previously written in book documentclass.
When it comes to the string:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em]
    {C & B \\
     C^*(E) & \\};
    \draw[->]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$\rho_{T,Q}$} (m-1-2)
     (m-2-1)  edge node [left] {$\exists \phi$} (m-1-1)
     edge node [right] {$\pi_{T,Q}$} (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

which perfectly compiles in book documentclass, doesn't compile in beamer documentclass.
The packages and libraries I use in the beamer, and are then already uploaded are the following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
```

Hope some of you guys can help me, thanks.

Comment: Please make this into a proper example that others can copy and test as is. We cannot do much with these sniplets. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: Hi, welcome. You're missing a `frame` environment, but beyond that my first guess is that you're facing the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer

Answer (score 1):

Okay thanks to Torbjørn T. for the comment. The answer to this problem is just alike ["Single ampersand used with wrong catcode" error using tikz matrix in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer)

i.e. Tikz and beamer sometimes don't agree on & being a column separator, so you just have to rename it with some other symbol, like `\&`

```
ampersand replacement=\&
```

then my code should have been:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em,ampersand replacement=\&]
    {C & B \\
     C^*(E) & \\};
    \draw[->]
    (m-1-1) edge node [above] {$\rho_{T,Q}$} (m-1-2)
     (m-2-1)  edge node [left] {$\exists \phi$} (m-1-1)
     edge node [right] {$\pi_{T,Q}$} (m-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```