# Draw matrices side-by-side in tikz

Tags: tikz-matrix

I would like to achieve the next result in tikz:
[image]

However, I am only able to draw the matrices without the mathematical operations between them i.e. the dot product and the equal signs (having the same height for the parenthesis is a plus). Below I am attaching part of my code and how far I have reached so far.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usetikzlibrary{fit, calc, matrix, positioning, arrows.meta, intersections, through, backgrounds, patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
    \pgfplotsset{overwrite option/.style args={#1 with #2}{#1=#2,#1/.code=}}


\begin{frame}{MATRIX MULTIPLICATION}
    More graphically:
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \scriptsize
        \matrix (m)[
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        %minimum width=width("998888"),
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=)
        ] {
        a_{11} && \cdots && a_{1k} && \cdots &&  a_{1n} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        a_{i1} && \cdots && a_{ik} && \cdots &&  a_{in} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        a_{m1} && \cdots && a_{mk} && \cdots &&  a_{mn} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-3-1.south west) rectangle (m-3-5.north east);
        
    \begin{scope}[xshift=95pt]
        
        \matrix (m)[
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        %minimum width=width("998888"),
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=)
        ] {
        b_{11} && \cdots && b_{1j} && \cdots &&  b_{1p} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        b_{k1} && \cdots && b_{kj} && \cdots &&  b_{kp} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        b_{n1} && \cdots && b_{nj} && \cdots &&  b_{np} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-5-3.south west) rectangle (m-1-3.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=200pt]
        
        \matrix (m)[
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        %minimum width=width("998888"),
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=)
        ] {
        c_{11} && \cdots && c_{1j} && \cdots &&  c_{1p} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        c_{i1} && \cdots && c_{ij} && \cdots &&  c_{ip} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        c_{m1} && \cdots && c_{mj} && \cdots &&  c_{mp} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-3-3.south west) rectangle (m-3-3.north east);
    \end{scope}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I'd use the `positioning` library to place the matrices next to each other, no need then to figure out the right `xshift`. (You could also do `\matrix (m2) at (95pt,0) ...` instead of the `scope`.)

Having named the matrices `m`, `m2` and `m3`, you can for example do

```
\path (m) -- node {$\cdot$} (m2)
      (m2) -- node {$=$} (m3);
```

to place the symbols midway between them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \scriptsize
        \matrix (m)[
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        %minimum width=width("998888"),
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=)
        ] {
        a_{11} && \cdots && a_{1k} && \cdots &&  a_{1n} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        a_{i1} && \cdots && a_{ik} && \cdots &&  a_{in} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        a_{m1} && \cdots && a_{mk} && \cdots &&  a_{mn} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-3-1.south west) rectangle (m-3-5.north east);
        

        
        \matrix (m2) [
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        %minimum width=width("998888"),
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=),
        right=of m
        ] {
        b_{11} && \cdots && b_{1j} && \cdots &&  b_{1p} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        b_{k1} && \cdots && b_{kj} && \cdots &&  b_{kp} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        b_{n1} && \cdots && b_{nj} && \cdots &&  b_{np} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-5-3.south west) rectangle (m-1-3.north east);

        
        \matrix (m3)[
        matrix of math nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        %minimum width=width("998888"),
        left delimiter=(,
        right delimiter=),
        right=of m2
        ] {
        c_{11} && \cdots && c_{1j} && \cdots &&  c_{1p} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        c_{i1} && \cdots && c_{ij} && \cdots &&  c_{ip} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        c_{m1} && \cdots && c_{mj} && \cdots &&  c_{mp} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-3-3.south west) rectangle (m-3-3.north east);

        \path (m) -- node {$\cdot$} (m2)
              (m2) -- node {$=$} (m3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Addendum

Note that in `beamer` you can't use a matrix directly, you need a `fragile` frame or use `ampersand replacement`, see for example ["Single ampersand used with wrong catcode" error using tikz matrix in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer)

Below I made the frame `fragile`. I also made a new style `pmat` that I applied to all the matrices, and I modified things a bit so that they actually fit in the frame.

[image]

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usetikzlibrary{fit, calc, matrix, positioning, arrows.meta, intersections, through, backgrounds, patterns}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
    \pgfplotsset{overwrite option/.style args={#1 with #2}{#1=#2,#1/.code=}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{MATRIX MULTIPLICATION}
    More graphically:
    
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    pmat/.style={
       matrix of math nodes,
       nodes={font=\footnotesize\strut, inner sep=1.5pt},
       left delimiter=(,
       right delimiter=),
       }
       ]

        \matrix (m)[pmat] {
        a_{11} && \cdots && a_{1k} && \cdots &&  a_{1n} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        a_{i1} && \cdots && a_{ik} && \cdots &&  a_{in} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        a_{m1} && \cdots && a_{mk} && \cdots &&  a_{mn} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-3-1.south west) rectangle (m-3-5.north east);
        
        
        \matrix (m2) [pmat,right=of m] {
        b_{11} && \cdots && b_{1j} && \cdots &&  b_{1p} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        b_{k1} && \cdots && b_{kj} && \cdots &&  b_{kp} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        b_{n1} && \cdots && b_{nj} && \cdots &&  b_{np} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-5-3.south west) rectangle (m-1-3.north east);

        
        \matrix (m3)[pmat,right=of m2] {
        c_{11} && \cdots && c_{1j} && \cdots &&  c_{1p} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        &&\vdots  \\
        c_{i1} && \cdots && c_{ij} && \cdots &&  c_{ip} \\
        \vdots &&        && \vdots &&        && \vdots  \\
        c_{m1} && \cdots && c_{mj} && \cdots &&  c_{mp} \\
        } ;
        
        \draw (m-3-3.south west) rectangle (m-3-3.north east);

        \path (m) -- node {$\cdot$} (m2)
              (m2) -- node {$=$} (m3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, many thanks mate

Comment: @RubénPérezSanz In `beamer` it wouldn't have worked perfectly, you need a `fragile` frame to use a matrix, see my updated answer.

Comment: True, know all the known errors to me are gone. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks! For me, the gap between the matrices is fixed. Is there a way to adjust the gap dynamically based on the size of the component in between the matrices?

Comment: @LucasAschenbach Sorry for the late reply, haven't logged on for a while. You could perhaps use relative positioning for everything. I.e.,  right after the first `\matrix` add `\node [right=of m] {$\cdot$};`, right after the second add `\node [right=of m2] {$=$};`, and remove the `\path` at the end.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, that's also what I ended up going with. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

With use of the `\vphantom{b_{ij}}` beginning of each rows with variables in the first and last matrix:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, 
                calc, 
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                fit, 
                intersections, 
                matrix, 
                positioning, patterns,
                through
                }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{MATRIX MULTIPLICATION}

    More graphically:
    
\[
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every matrix/.style = {matrix of math nodes,
                       nodes in empty cells,
                       nodes = {inner sep=2pt, font=\scriptsize},
                       left delimiter=(,
                       right delimiter=),
                       inner sep=0pt
                       },
                        ]    
\matrix (m1)
    {
\vphantom{b_{ij}}
    a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1k} & \cdots &  a_{1n} \\
    \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
\vphantom{b_{ij}}
    a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{ik} & \cdots &  a_{in} \\
    \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
\vphantom{b_{ij}}
    a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mk} & \cdots &  a_{mn} \\
    } ;
\draw (m1-3-1.south west) rectangle (m1-3-5.north east);
\node (m1a) [right=2mm of m1] {$\cdot$};
\matrix (m2)[right=2mm of m1a] 
    {
    b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1j} & \cdots &  b_{1p} \\
    \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
    b_{k1} & \cdots & b_{kj} & \cdots &  b_{kp} \\
    \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
    b_{n1} & \cdots & b_{nj} & \cdots &  b_{np} \\
    } ;
\draw (m2-5-3.south west) rectangle (m2-1-3.north east);
\node (m2a) [right=2mm of m2] {$=$};
\matrix (m3) [right=2mm of m2a] 
    {
\vphantom{b_{ij}}
    c_{11} & \cdots & c_{1j} & \cdots &  c_{1p} \\
    \vdots &        & \vdots &        &\vdots  \\
\vphantom{b_{ij}}
    c_{i1} & \cdots & c_{ij} & \cdots &  c_{ip} \\
    \vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
\vphantom{b_{ij}}
    c_{m1} & \cdots & c_{mj} & \cdots &  c_{mp} \\
    } ;
\draw (m3-3-3.south west) rectangle (m3-3-3.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it did the tric

Comment: @RubénPérezSanz, if it , you can up-vote answer. As well accept answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`. This environment is similar to `{pmatrix}` of `amsmath` but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells of the array. It's easy to use these nodes to draw the rectangles with Tikz.

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{MATRIX MULTIPLICATION}
    More graphically:

\NiceMatrixOptions{small,create-large-nodes,columns-width=4mm}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{ccccc<{\vphantom{b_{np}}}}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1j} & \cdots &  a_{1p} \\
\vdots &        & \vdots &        &\vdots  \\
a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{ij} & \cdots &  a_{ip} \\
\vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mj} & \cdots &  a_{mp} 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (3-1-large.south west) rectangle (3-5-large.north east);
\end{pNiceArray}
\cdot
\begin{pNiceArray}{ccccc}
b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1j} & \cdots &  b_{1p} \\
\vdots &        & \vdots &        &\vdots  \\
b_{k1} & \cdots & b_{kj} & \cdots &  b_{kp} \\
\vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
b_{n1} & \cdots & b_{nj} & \cdots &  b_{np} 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (5-3-large.south west) rectangle (1-3-large.north east);
\end{pNiceArray}
=
\begin{pNiceArray}{ccccc<{\vphantom{b_{np}}}}
c_{11} & \cdots & c_{1j} & \cdots &  c_{1p} \\
\vdots &        & \vdots &        &\vdots  \\
c_{i1} & \cdots & c_{ij} & \cdots &  c_{ip} \\
\vdots &        & \vdots &        & \vdots  \\
c_{m1} & \cdots & c_{mj} & \cdots &  c_{mp} 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \draw (3-3-large.south west) rectangle (3-3-large.north east);
\end{pNiceArray}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: But matrices haven't the same sizes :-)

Comment: @Zarko: That's right. I will change to have the same size.