# Place text next to a down arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, matrices, braces

I would like to place a text next to an arrow. The figure below shows how I would like it to look. I tried to use the commands `^` and `_` and also `\hspace` and `\vspace`, but it is not getting the way you want. Maybe there is a command like `\overbrace` or `\underbrace` that helps me, but I don't know it.

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand\myarrow{%
  \tikz\draw[red,dashed,thick,-Triangle] (0,0) -- ++(0,-1.1);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\begin{array}{cccccc}
 & f(x) & = & \sqrt{x^2 + 500^2} \cdot 640,00 & + &  (2000 - x) \cdot 312,00\\ 
  &  &  &  &  &  \\
   &  &  & \myarrow_{\color{red}(\sqrt{x})' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}} &  & \myarrow \\
 &  &  &  &  &  \\ 
\Rightarrow & f'(x) & = & 640,00\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 500^2}}2x & + & 312,00(-1) 
\end{array} $
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I need this derivative to be higher. Another way I tried was to put it to the side as text, but the `\tiny` and `\small` commands are not working.

PS: I have already asked some questions about how to do some commands for a presentation, I am trying to look for the answers, but I believe that they are not trivial things and are difficult to find on the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better (in my opinion) to use a Ti*k*Z matrix, since you need Ti*k*Z. Then you can use matrix nodes and the result it's very simple. For the big size my solution is to put `\displaymath` inside the math and you have it.

I'll give you an example with a couple of changes (I personally like it better how it looks like this, but change it to your liking).

```
\documentclass {beamer}
\usepackage    {cancel}
\usepackage    {siunitx} % Better look for decimal numbers
\usepackage    {tikz}

\sisetup       {group-minimum-digits=3,output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  % It's necessary for TikZ matrix and beamer to change the ampersands
  \matrix(D)[matrix of nodes,row sep=2cm,column sep=0cm,ampersand replacement=\&]
  {
                  \& $f(x)$ \& $=$ \& $\underbrace{\num{640,00}\cdot\sqrt{x^2+500^2}}$ \& $+$
                  \& $\underbrace{\num{312,00}\cdot(\num{2000}-x)}$\\
    $\Rightarrow$ \& $f'(x)$ \& $=$ \& $\displaystyle\overbrace{\num{640,00}\cdot\frac{\cancel{2}x}{\cancel{2}\sqrt{x^2+500}}}$ \& $+$
                  \& $\overbrace{\num{312,00}\cdot(-1)}$\\
  };
  \draw[thick,red,dashed,-Triangle] (D-1-4) -- (D-2-4);
  \draw[thick,red,dashed,-Triangle] (D-1-6) -- (D-2-6);
  \node[red] at ($(D-1-4)!0.5!(D-2-4)$) [right] {$\displaystyle(\sqrt{x})'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:
[image]

**EDIT**: My first attempt was a standalone instead of a beamer. Putting the Ti*k*Z matrix inside a frame produces an error. There is a conflict with beamer an Ti*k*Z. The solution was to change the ampersand `&` for another thing, in my case `\&`. There is more information in: ["Single ampersand used with wrong catcode" error using tikz matrix in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer)

Comment: It was good, I didn't understand how to make the smaller size of the red part next to the arrow.

Comment: I'm giving a presentation in `\documentclass{beamer}`, and your code is giving an error. I liked what you did, do I need another package for the beamer case?

Comment: It works form me in beamer too. You need only the listed packages: cancel (if you want to cancel in the fraction) and siunitx (if you want my display of numbers, if you not remove the `\num`s).

Comment: For making bigger the derivative you need to put the `\displaystyle' command in the math environment.

Comment: The code that is giving an error is `\sisetup       {group-minimum-digits=3,output-decimal-marker={,}}`

Comment: If remove this code the error is in `\end{frame}`

Comment: Did you put the siunitx package? If you did I don't know the problem. But you can remove the `\sisetup{...}' and all the `\num{...}` commands. I think that it'll work this way too

Comment: I used the package siunitx and if I remove the error is in `\ end {frame}`

Comment: I think I found the error. I'm editing in a moment. Take a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I propose this other solution, which doesn't require TiKZ – just an `alignat*  environment and the` eqparbox` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{alignat*}{2}
 f(x) & = \eqmathbox[L]{\sqrt{x^2 + 500^2} \cdot 640,00} & & + \eqmathbox[R]{(2000 - x) \cdot 312,00}\\
  &\phantom{ = } \eqmathbox[L]{\scriptstyle\color{red}\biggl\downarrow(\sqrt{u})' = \tfrac{u'}{2\sqrt{u}}} & & \phantom{ + } \eqmathbox[L]{\scriptstyle\color{red}\biggl\downarrow}\\%& & \myarrow \\
  \Rightarrow f'(x) & = \eqmathbox[L]{640,00\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2 + 500^2}}} & & + \eqmathbox[R]{312,00(-1)}
\end{alignat*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!