# Why is the following Tikz picture in beamer overlapped?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-matrix

In overleaf with the code below I got the following figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer} %works also for article

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

% units
\newcommand{\myunit}{1 cm}
\tikzset{
    node style sp/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=\myunit},
    node style ge/.style={circle,minimum size=\myunit},
    arrow style mul/.style={draw,sloped,midway,fill=white},
    arrow style plus/.style={midway,sloped,fill=white},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
% matrices
\matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes = {node style ge},
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (0,0)
{
 |[node style sp]| a_{11} & |[node style sp]| a_{12} &|[node style sp]| a_{13}  \\
   a_{21} & a_{22} &  a_{23} \\
};
\node [draw,below=10pt] at (A.south) 
    { $A: 2\times 3$};

\matrix (B) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes = {node style ge},
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (4*\myunit,4*\myunit)
{
|[node style sp]| d_{11} & d_{12} \\
|[node style sp]| d_{21} & d_{22} \\
|[node style sp]| d_{31} & d_{32} \\
};
\node [draw,right=50pt] at (B.south) 
    { $D: 3\times 2$};
% matrix result
\matrix (C) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes = {node style ge},
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (4*\myunit,0)
{
  |[node style sp,red]| c_{11} & c_{12}  \\
  c_{21} & c_{22} \\
};
\node [draw,below=10pt] at (C.south) 
    { $C = AD: 2\times 2$};
% arrow
\draw[blue] (A-2-1.north) -- (C-2-1.north);
\draw[blue] (A-1-1.north) -- (C-1-1.north);
\draw[blue] (B-1-2.west)  -- (C-1-1.east);
\draw[blue] (B-1-1.west)  -- (C-1-1.west);
\draw[<->,red](A-1-1) to[in=180,out=90]
    node[arrow style mul] (x) {$a_{11}\times d_{11}$} (B-1-1);
\draw[<->,red](A-1-2) to[in=180,out=90]
    node[arrow style mul] (y) {$a_{12}\times d_{21}$} (B-2-1);
\draw[<->,red](A-1-3) to[in=180,out=90]
    node[arrow style mul] (z) {$a_{13}\times d_{31}$} (B-3-1);
\draw[red,->] (x) to node[arrow style plus] {$+$} (y);%
\draw[red,->] (y) to node[arrow style plus] {$+$} (z)%
    to (C-1-1.north west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, when I copied the same code in a beamer document class I got overlapped matrix elements. I am trying to figure out what is wrong but I am unable to find what I'm missing and I got the following picture:

[image]

Could there be any conflict with any other package/s?

Comment: Basically https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer?noredirect=1&lq=1 I suppose

Comment: I don't get overlap with your code. Did you compile often enough? Or is your code really inside of a frame? If yes, than it's a duplicate of the ampersand question.

Comment: Given that your image shows a frametitle, I suppose your code does not reproduce your problem... The code as it is in your question would give https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbnmc.png

Comment: It worked with ampersand question and changing the `&` by adding `\&`. Thnks!